# Simple question about Lebesgue density points of open sets

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, geometric-measure-theory

I have a question regarding Lebesgue density points.

Assume that $E \subset \Omega$, where $E$ and $\Omega$ are two **open** subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$; now define the function
$$D(x):=\lim_{r \to 0^+} \frac{| E \cap B_r (x)|}{|B_r (x)|},$$
where $| \cdot |$ denotes the Lebesgue measure in $\mathbb{R}^N$.
Now define the set:
$$E^{(t)}:= \left\{ x \in \Omega: D(x)=t \right\}.$$

**Question**: since $E$ is open, can I say that $E=E^{(1)}$?

My intuition says that if $x \in E=int(E)$ then $D(x)=1$ but my question is if also the conversely is true.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there could be $E^{(1)}$ points outside of $E$.  Consider these $\Omega = \mathbb R$ and $E = \mathbb R \setminus \{0\}$.  Even though $0 \notin E$, we still have $D(0) = 1$.

If $E$ is open we do have
$$
E \subseteq E^{(1)} \subseteq \overline{E}\\
E^c \supseteq E^{(0)} \supseteq \left(\overline{E}\right)^c
$$
where I used ${}^c$ for the complement.  Any points outside $E^{(0)} \cup E^{(1)}$ are on the boundary of $E$.

Comment: Really thanks GEdar. In my case $E$ is the super-level set of a function $f$, i.e. $E=\left\{ f >t \right\}$, with $f$ of class $C^1$, and I wish to find $E^{(1)} \cap \left\{ x_n= c \right\}$, for some $c$ fixed, $x_n$ the $n-$th component. Is there something that can I say about this intersection? Thanks in advance.